# Probability with conditional

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My Question reads:

Three different numbers from {1,..., 10} are picked. If the largest is 7, what is the probability
that the number 5 is among the chosen ones?

So far I have been thinking of the size of my sample space. I have determined it to be 10*9*8 because we have distinct numbers.

Let A=the largest number chosen was 7

Let B=the number 5 is chosen

I want to find P(B|A), but I am not too sure how to find P(A) or P( B $\cap$ A) because I want to use the formula P(B|A)= P( A $\cap$ B) / P(A) .

For P(A) would I need to consider all the cases where 7 is not the largest number chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the largest number is a $7$, there are $6\choose 2$ ways to pick the two smaller numbers. Out of these choices there are $5\choose 2$ ways to avoid picking a $5$. Therefore the probability is $1-\frac{5\choose 2}{6\choose 2}=1 - \frac{5\cdot 4}{6\cdot 5}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I am not too sure what your P(A) and P (B $\cap$ A) is here in your solution.

Comment: @Sam:  He is not using that formula.  He is simply counting successes and total cases where the largest number is $7$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see, I was just trying to see how this would look like in terms of P(A) and such without necessarily counting.

Comment: @Sam I've added a section to show how John's figures fit into the Bayes' formation.  He's just used experience to jump straight to the third equation (though he used the complement to do so, which is also okay).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you so much! It is very clear to me now what is going on. I just needed more of a visual to understand the steps involved.

Comment: $P(A)=\frac{6\choose 2}{10\choose 3} = \frac{15}{105}=\frac{1}{7}$.

If your choice contains $5$ and $7$ then your third number must be one of $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ so $P(A\cap B)=\frac{5}{105}=\frac{1}{21}$. Dividing one by the other gives $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the sample space is $10\times 9\times 8$ if you are looking
at **ordered** selections of three numbers. In this problem it would be more natural
to consider unordered selections; there are $\binom{10}3$ of these.

Now $P(A)$ will be the number of selections of three numbers from $\{1,\ldots,7\}$ that include $7$ divided by the number of selections from $\{1,\ldots,10\}$. You also want $P(A\cap B)$.
To find this you need the number of selections that include $5$ and $7$
and have $7$ as the largest number. So the third number has to be $1$, $2$, $3$ ,$4$ or $6$.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I meant to write intersection instead. Yes, I had originally thought of doing 10 choose 3, but the fact that it said distinct numbers made me think or order.

Comment: @Sam $\binom{10}3$ is the number of unordered selections of three **distinct** things from ten.